# Retain and Keep Variables Macro

Tags: sas

I have a large dataset with a number of variables (columns). The variable names include

- JUNE19_53410_Actual,
- JUNE19_53410_Actual_Per_Unit,
- JUNE19_53410_Budget,
- JUNE19_53410_Budget_Per_Unit,
- JUNE19_53410_Variance

and so on... there are hundreds as the months and accounts change.

I want to write a MACRO where the only variables included in my new dataset 1) are ordered Acutal then Budget, and alternate by month so for example, the new 
table would look like:

```
 JUNE19_53410_Actual  JUNE19_53410_Budget   AUG19_53410_Actual AUG19_53410_Budget 
  $12,000                $34,000            $23,000            $14,000
  $13,000                $64,000            $83,000            $11,000
```

I tried the following code but am getting an erro when I put it into my data step

```
 %MACRO Keeping;
 retain
 &x._Actual  &x._Budget;
 keep 
 &x._Actual  &x._Budget;
 %MEND Keeping;

 data test;
 set June_2019;
 %Keeping;
 run;
```

Comment: You are getting an error because you have not defined what the macro variable x is. Also are you looking to split the tables by month?

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen to use this schema (very wide data set) with important data such as date, number (is it a plan/store/department/division?) as metadata and part of variable names ? Your 'problems' will only grow as new months are added. How many rows are there ?  What differentiates one row from another ?

Comment: How big are each of these data sets? I'm probably beating a dead horse here, so last response. You really, really want to stack these data sets and add the month and number in as variables. That's a trivial task that takes about 5 minutes and makes you not need macros and loops anymore and your code would be cleaner, easier to manage in the future.

Comment: It looks like my post was edited by someone, their edits do not reflect the way in which I want my data displayed which has created confusion!!! I have since then edited it back to my original post. In regards to the questions the new table I would have 120 columns by the end of the year(2 for each month, 5 for each cost center and 2 for budget and actual). The data sets are pretty small and I cant stack them because I would like a side by side comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why a macro?

They way you use a macro "function" hardly reduces the code and makes it harder to read.
It is easyer to use a macro variable.

## What I would do

```
/* List the variables you want */
%let myVars =
        JUNE19_53410_Actual JUNE19_53410_Budget
        AUG19_53410_Actual AUG19_53410_Budget
        ...
        DEC19_53410_Actual DEC19_53410_Budget
        ;
/* Define what dataset you create */
data want;
    /* I specify the order of the variables with a length statement */ 
    length &myVars 8;
    /* Read in your data */
    set have;
    /* keep only what you need */
    keep &myVars;
run;
```

## Should you use `retain`, `length` or `format`

SAS puts variables in the dataset in the order you mention them. The `set` statement "mentions" all variables in the input dataset and you cant change their order anymore. Therefore you should mention your variables before the `set` statement. You have many options for that.

Suppose you want `a` and `b` to be the first variable in your dataset, then you have different options

### `length a b 8;`

This defines `a` and `b` as numerics, stored in 8 bytes each (the maximal and also default length of numerics in sas). Your input data might have smaller variable sizes. Then the side effect of this `length` statement is, that your output dataset will be larger. No big deal.
You can do the same for character variableslike in `length first_name last_name $32;` but this has a more risky side effect: If these variables are longer on your input dataset, you might truncate them.

### 'retain a b;'

This avoids the side effects mentioned above and is therefore SAS recomends it. However I avoid it, because it changes the way SAS treats the values of these variables. See below.

### `format a b 12.4;`

This specifies should be printed in 12 positions, of which 4 are decimals. It implicitely defines them as numerics, because this is a numeric format and the length defaulds to 8 bytes.

### Other options

You might also use the [`label`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201974.htm) or the `attribute` statement here.

## What `retain` does

By defauls, SAS sets all variables to missing for each observation (i.e. row).
The Retain statement is used to prevent this for certain variables, like in

```
Data running_total;
    set transactions; /* a dataset with amount */
    retain total 0;   /* initialize as 0 for the first observation */
    total = total + amount;
run;
```

`retain total 0;` is shorthand for `retain total; if _N_ = 1 then total = 0;`

In your code, the 'retain' has no influence on the values of the variables, as the first thing you do is overwriting them with the input in your `set` statement.

However, if you add assignments before your `set` statement, retain does have an impact on the values of these variables. Therefore I avoid it and use the `length` statement for numeric variables.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with that. The retain statement will not have any effect on variables that are read from the data set. Format actually will require you know the format for each variable (which happens to be trivial in this case). In fact retain is the SAS suggested way to do this reordering: http://support.sas.com/kb/8/395.html

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the ordering of columns in a dataset is not meaningful except when viewing the datasets using any viewer. PROCs like PRINT will allow you to specify the order.

Nevertheless, if you really want to preserve a default order, you could do something like this if you have all the prefixes in a macro variable:

```
%let months = %str(JUNE19_53410 AUG19_1234);

%macro genlist;

    %let ii = 1;
    %do %while (%scan(&months, &ii, %str( )) ~= %str());
      %let col = %scan(&months, &ii, %str( ));

      &col._actual &col._budget

      %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);
    %end;

%mend;

data want;
  retain 
    %genlist;
  ;
  set have;
  keep
    %genlist;
  ;

run;
```

This will keep the following fields in the following order:

```
JUNE19_53410_actual
JUNE19_53410_budget
AUG19_1234_actual
AUG19_1234_budget
```

If your number of columns are too large to populate manually, then you may need another code to generate the months macro variable. In such cases you may exceed the 65536 limit and may have to resort to other techniques like PROC EXECUTE.

Comment: See my comment above, my post was edited by someone where it made what I was asking incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Stack them all into one data set and add an indicator variable.

- INDSNAME on the SET statement stores the input data set name and it's
  written to the INPUT_FILE variable.
- SCAN() parses the name for the different components
- INPUT(, monyy5.) tries to convert the month to a SAS date for sorting correctly. This
  may not work because you have JUNE2019 vs JUN2019 which is usually the standard. So 
  you can keep it in character and convert in a different manner.

  ```
  data want;
      length source input_file $50.;
      set <list of data sets> indsname = source;

      input_file = source;
      month = input(scan(input_file, 2, '._'), monyy5.);
      format month monyy5.;
      code = scan(input_file, 3, '._');
      budget_actual = scan(input_file, -1, '_'); * you can recode to what you need but seems like last bit will be enough; 

  run;
  ```

Now you have a single data set you can easily filter, sort, query or use for reporting on demand with all of your data. No more loops needed for cleaning or restructuring the data or simple sorting.